# Выполнить MySQL запрос в определённое время

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Нужно выполнить MySQL запрос в определённое время, а именно каждую ночь ровно в 00:00 удалить необходимые данные из таблицы. Тоесть как только на часах сервера будет 00:00, то запрос выполняется.

Comment: @Fike, оформи как ответ

Comment: Нужно выполнить команду из php

Comment: @Rammsteinik, приведенный пример запустит php-скрипт, расположенный по адресу `/home/user/cron-script.php` (конечно, можно указать любой другой путь).

Comment: Можно подробнее про MySQL Events?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, информации по этому вопросу не мало. Вот, к примеру, первые попавшиеся ссылки:

1. [Использование событий MySQL на практике][1]
2. [События (events) в MySQL (планировщик заданий аля CRON)][2]
3. И конечно же первоисточник - [Using the Event Scheduler][3]

   [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/123391/
   [2]: http://blog.nagaychenko.com/2009/11/30/scheduler-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-event-%D0%B2-mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F-cron/
   [3]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Rammsteinik](/users/11413/rammsteinik)](/users/11413/rammsteinik), если вам надо производить действия только с БД, то можно обойтись и без cron-а. Начиная с версии мускула 5.1.6, есть возможность создавать "планировщик задач" (MySQL Events). Это будет вполне  достаточно для вашей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Подобные вещи управляются планировщиком, в линуксе это cron

```
user@host:~$ crontab -e
```

Откроет окно редактирования скрипта планировщика, в который нужно добавить новую строчку типа

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/cron-script.php
```

Которая будет запускать указанную выше команду ежедневно в 00:00